# Hard to debug under test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hard to debug under test environment

This is my first time run in **test environment**

Get the error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The bug is kind of troublesome,

Because it din't give me any other information

#### controller

```
  def index
    binding.pry
    @tool_cvt_firmware_ui_tests = Tool::Cvt::FirmwareUiTest.all
  end

  def create
    @tool_cvt_firmware_ui_test = Tool::Cvt::FirmwareUiTest.new(tool_cvt_firmware_ui_test_params)
    binding.pry    

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tool_cvt_firmware_ui_test.save
        binding.pry
    end
 end
```

#### routes

```
  localized do
    namespace :tool do
      namespace :cvt do
        resources :firmware_ui_tests
      end
    end    
  end
```

#### Error

```
[2014-12-17 15:27:13] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/route_translator-3.2.4/lib/route_translator/extensions/action_controller.rb:8:in `block in set_locale_from_url'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/route_translator-3.2.4/lib/route_translator/extensions/action_controller.rb:24:in `with_host_locale'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/route_translator-3.2.4/lib/route_translator/extensions/action_controller.rb:8:in `set_locale_from_url'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:298:in `call'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:298:in `block in halting'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.1.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
```

#### Concern file

```
require 'active_support/concern'
module RemoteFwUiServer
  include ActiveSupport::Concern
  attr_accessor :params
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is this line `attr_accessor :params`

It works after I removed it.

But the error log is so ambiguous